Setting position of PlotLegends affect position of PlotLabel
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> 400,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotLabel -> "a"]

gives

the PlotLabel "a" is right at the center of the frame.
However, if I add PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> 400,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotLabel -> "a",
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]]

gives

The plotlegends is not centered to the frame, but the plotlabel "a" is still centered.
Also note that the graphics' orange frame and the legend are separated. The FullForm is Legended[Graphics[....]]
Now if I slightly adjust the position of plotlegends like
p=Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> 400,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotLabel -> "a",
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.55, Below}]]


You can see the plotlabel "a" is not centered anymore. Also note that the legend is now "inside " the graphics' orange frame, althougth the FullForm is still Legended[Graphics[....]]
However, First@p gives

PlotLabel "a" is still centered!!.
What is more, the position of "a" is not related to the value of Placed. For example
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> 400,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotLabel -> "a",
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.9, Below}]]

gives

It is obvious that PlotLabel is centered relative to the frame by default. But why does using Placed in PlotLegends affect the positioning of PlotLabel? How can I keep PlotLabel centered to the frame when I use Placed for PlotLegends?

Worse than @eldo's answer, but decided to post it anyway.
Overlay[{Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400/GoldenRatio}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabel -> "a"], 
  LineLegend[{ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2]}, Automatic, 
   LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 400/GoldenRatio}}]}, 
 Alignment -> {0.125, 1}, ImageSize -> All]



Thank you so much for your answer. But Overlay is not a graphics. It would not be consistent with some of my customized tool functions. For example, Overlay object can not be Show.

Haha, I know it is only useful for output an image. PlotLabel -> Placed["a", Automatic] is not valid. I think PlotLabel may have some defects.

I cannot explain this odd behaviour. A quick fix with Row and and an appropriate amount of spacings:
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6},
 ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotLabel -> Row[{Spacer[40], "a"}],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.55, Below}]]


Update
You could define a as the upper FrameLabel:
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {"x", "a"}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.55, Below}]]



Hi, eldo, Thank you so much for a quick solution. I still prefer some better solution without manual adjustment. I update my post with new findings. Please take a look if you have time.

See update, I hope it helps

This is a really clever thick. Thank you so much! It helps!
